# sharepoint file upload

Tags: sharepoint, file, upload

I can upload a 250MB file to sharepoint 2007 but nothing larger.  I have changed the two webconfig file, set the admin site to 2047MB and it still fails.

Please help this was to be completed asap.

thanx

Comment: Can you clarify the places you made the changes exactly, in case you missed something obvious?

Comment: Thanks for getting back.

I'm past the default I can do 250MB but that's it.


Stsadm.exe ?o setproperty ?pn large?file?chunk?size ?pv <size in bytes>.


<location path=”upload.aspx”> 
    <system.web> 
      <httpRuntime executionTimeout=”999999″ maxRequestLength=”2097151″ /> 
    </system.web>

<httpRuntime maxRequestLength=”51200″ />
Replacement line
<httpRuntime executionTimeout=”999999″ maxRequestLength=”51200″ />

max web part

Comment: IMHO you should not add such a huge file in SharePoint... What's inside?

Comment: we have video files that range from 100MB-800MB

Answer (score 1):

SPS ignore the file size setting for max file size, according to various testings.

Instead see KB 925083  for info on how to change size http://support.microsoft.com/kb/925083

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me but I did and still can't get past 250MB

Answer (score 0):

1. Please define "fail". Any specific error message, timeouts, etc?
2. How do you upload your files? Webinterface, WebDav Put, RPC, etc?
3. When you say "modified web.config", I assume you mean you setting maxAllowedContentLength property of the requestLimits node to something huge. Have you verified you set this correctly, by using small values and checking if it indeed blocks files?
4. Regarding step 3, or did you mean the executionTimeout setting on the httpRuntime? Verified you set it right by setting it to too small a value an checkin that it cuts short your requests?
5. By "setting the admin site", I assume you mean you set the Maximum upload size on the Virtual Server Settings page to something hue. Again, have you verified what the behaviour is when you choose too small a value there?

Note how step 3-5 are just the generic checklist shaped like questions... usually it helps going through the steps *one more time*.

Comment: Here is my err
Unable to complete this operation.  Please contact your administrator.   

at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.PutFile(String bstrUrl, String bstrWebRelativeUrl, Object varFile, PutFileOpt PutFileOpt, String bstrCreatedBy, String bstrModifiedBy, Int32 iCreatedByID, Int32 iModifiedByID, Object varTimeCreated, Object varTimeLastModified, Object varProperties, String bstrCheckinComment, UInt32& pdwVirusCheckStatus, String& pVirusCheckMessage)

Comment: The file fails through the map drive and web interface

Comment: I'm using II6 so I don't think there is a maxAllowedContentLength

Comment: Yes the execution timeout=999999 and the management page has 2047MB

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a situation where there are several "gates" that the file has to go through and it is getting caught by the narrowest.

There is also the question is it getting stopped during the upload or when it is being written to sharepoint.

Based on the other answers / cooments sounds like you have checked most things. There are a couple more you could try:

- Is there anything in machine.config that is blocking your settings in web.config (typical overrideable = false)
- Are the settings cached, have you tried restarting the machine?

here are a couple of links that might help:

http://spsstuff.blogspot.com/2006/03/how-to-change-maximum-file-upload-size.html

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/925083